# How to fixed route problem only / route working on live server not other?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 8 php 7.4. All route working fine on Local machine. But on Live serve Ubuntu 20.04 only one route is working that is / route.
My .htaccess file is in public folder and its content is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my route file is

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::post('user/login', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,    'login'])->name('user.login');
Route::post('user/registration', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'register'])->name('user.registration');
Route::get('/redirect', [\App\Http\Controllers\SocialAuthGoogleController::class, 'redirect']);
Route::get('/auth/google/callback', [\App\Http\Controllers\SocialAuthGoogleController::class, 'callback']);

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
Route::get('logout', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::get('show/energy/service/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\EnergyServiceController::class, 'show'])->name('show.energy.service');
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('student', [\App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'index'])->name('student');
Route::post('student/add', [\App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('student.add');
Route::get('student/edit/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'edit'])->name('student.edit');
Route::post('student/update', [\App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'update'])->name('student.update');
Route::get('student/delete/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'delete'])->name('student.delete');
});
```

When I visit on any link This page appear
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IRMt.png)

How can i resolved this thanks in advance

Comment: Did you enable `mod_rewrite`? Check [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04) to know how and why!

Comment: yes but its still producing same issue